# Help identifying the fuse used inside a Parkside 20V lithium-ion power tool battery

Tags: batteries, identification, lithium-ion, fuses

I blew the fuse inside my Parkside power tool 20 V 4 Ah battery and was wanting to fix it.

There is a guy just soldering the broken circular fuse. The image below is taken from [this video](https://youtu.be/A6LYNa3-n90?t=171) at approximately the location that the video is set to start at, but I want to do it better with a proper fuse replacement.

The fuse is a metal strip with a hole in it, leaving two "legs" for current.These appear to be effectively two parallel fuses - so replacing with one fuse may be in order.

[image]

I'd like help identifying the type and value of this fuse, as I cannot find anything close to a match.

I guess the value is about 40-60 A.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  If you want help identifying a component you should start by providing a well focused high res picture of the component plus surrounding circuit, along with a description of the device/circuit. Expecting people to watch a YouTube video for details is not in line with site guidance, and your question will be closed.

Comment: Why don't use something like this https://www.belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/circuitprotection/ds-CP-0ACA-series.pdf

Comment: Edited, reopened, answered.

Comment: Person who flagged question: The (stupid) system does not allow me to accept your flag or to send back a private comment. The flag was reasonably reasonable :-) - video was started at relevant location BUT still annoying to need to access it.  Hopefully OK now.

Comment: @Antonio51 's suggested protector looks like a good idea. I'd suggest that no bigger than a 30A one or equivalent would be a good start. || 40A blow in about 400 seconds. 60A blow in 10 seconds. || Even the 25A gives 50 s at 40A and 2s at 60A. ||The cells really do not like 60A.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a 5S2P cell arrangement giving, for LiIon cells, 4.2V x 5 = 21V fully charged.  Each cell will be 4Ah/2 = 2Ah.

If they are 18650 size than 2000 mAh indicates a "power" cell - ie rated for high current rather than capacity.

The following cells may not be the ones in your unit - but it seems reasonably possible that they or something similar are used.

[This webpage](https://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/Parkside%20INR18650E%202000mAh%20(Blue)%20UK.html) suggests that they are (may be) INR18650E's - which could simply be a generic cell.
However, they provide an excellent set of discharge curves, with 20A/cell looking perhaps acceptable, and 30A/cellcausing overheating or fuse blowing.
On that basis a 40A fuse would probably be a "sensible starting point" (2 cells at 20A each).

Graph from [here](https://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/Parkside%20INR18650E%202000mAh%20(Blue)%20UK.html) (same link as above)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reopening the question and your considered answer. The batteries in mine are 18650P 2000mAh INR 19/66.I don't think this makes any difference to 40A being a good start. I think that Antonio's suggested fuse is nice with respect to dimensions.The existing fuse is 12mm by 8mm. I thought the time to blow may be a little slow. DigiKey were also very expensive for these bel fuse 0aca type fuses when shipping was taken into account for these £1 fuses especially if ordered alone. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @user357116  **Informally** I'd suggest that the cells will probably fare "not too badly" at 20A each for a while. Antonios [Bel fuses](https://www.belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/circuitprotection/ds-CP-0ACA-series.pdf) or similar rated at 20A will blow at 40A in about 4s but at 60A in 0.2S. That sounds bearable IF you do not wish to try 40A except incidentally. || The 25A fuse blows in 1 minute at 40A and 2s at 60A (all approximate). That's better IF you want to push 40A for say 10S at a time BUT at 60A the battery fuse may blow first. || I'd probably start with a 20A with similar specs.